# How to connect to a database in Zig?

Tags: zig

I was working on a cli type app with Zig, I couldn't find a way to connect with a database to store my data. Is there a native way to connect to a database with Zig? I couldn't find any docs through google. If there is not a native way to connect to a database how can I download dependencies through the native modules in Zig.

```
const std = @import("std");
const uri = std.Uri.parse("http://127.0.0.1:8000") catch unreachable;

var gpa = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{}){};
const alloc = gpa.allocator();

const Pkg = struct {
    name: [:0]u8,
    src: []u8,
};

const Config = struct {
    id: []u8,
    name: [:0]u8,
    pkgs: ?std.ArrayList(Pkg) = null,
};

pub fn main() !void {
    var client: std.http.Client = .{ .allocator = alloc };

    var req = try client.request(.GET, uri, .{ .allocator = alloc }, .{});
    defer req.deinit();

    try req.start();
    try req.wait();
}
```

This is my code and I am using Zig version: 0.11.0-dev.3395+1e7dcaa3a edge.

Comment: I'd expect to need a library to work with a database. What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples on zig cookbook:

- https://zigcc.github.io/zig-cookbook/14-01-sqlite.html
- https://zigcc.github.io/zig-cookbook/14-02-postgres.html
- https://zigcc.github.io/zig-cookbook/14-03-mysql.html